# How do you add a custom post type when registering a new user in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently customising this theme https://houzez.co/

When a user registers, they can select a user role on registration. For example an agent signs up and they are added to the list of agents in the backend, which is backend menu item.

I have created a custom post type for the user roles in functions.php

What I want to do is, every time a user with a custom user roles signs up, there they are added to the custom post type below.

```
/*Custom Post type start*/
function homease_post_type_insurer() {
$supports = array(
    'title', // post title
    'editor', // post content
    'author', // post author
    'thumbnail', // featured images
    'excerpt', // post excerpt
    'custom-fields', // custom fields
    'comments', // post comments
    'revisions', // post revisions
    'post-formats', // post formats
);
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Insurers', 'plural'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Insurer', 'singular'),
    'menu_name' => _x('View Insurers', 'admin menu'),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x('Insurer', 'admin bar'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Insurer'),
    'new_item' => __('New Insurer'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Insurer'),
    'view_item' => __('View Insurer'),
    'all_items' => __('All Insurers'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Insurer'),
    'not_found' => __('No Insurer found.'),
);
$args = array(
    'supports' => $supports,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'insurer'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
);
register_post_type('Insurer', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'homease_post_type_insurer');
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a new post on user registration, you can use the WordPress hook `user_register` which fires after the user is registered. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/

```php
add_action( 'user_register', 'he_create_custom_post_type_for_user' , 20, 1 );
function he_create_custom_post_type_for_user($user_id){
    $user_obj = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
    // replace 'your_role' with the role you want.
    if (in_array('your_role', (array) $user_obj->roles ) ){
        // array for wp_insert_post https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'   => $user_obj->display_name , // Make the post title the name of the user
            'post_type'    => 'Insurer',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_author'  => $user_id,
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        // Your new post has post id $post_id - add update_post_meta ($post_id) if you want to add meta.
    }
}
```